# What other defects did Marx think there was to hitherto existing materialism?

Tags: marx, marxism, feuerbach

> [The chief defect](https://www.marxists.org/archive/marx/works/1845/theses/theses.htm) of all hitherto existing materialism – that of
> Feuerbach included – is that the thing, reality, sensuousness, is
> conceived only in the form of the object.

Does Marx allege any other mistakes, and is he right to?

Comment: Any other mistakes of Feuerbach or of some other already existing theory of materlialism?

Comment: universal to all hitherto existing materialism, i guess is what i'm asking

Comment: It is not easy I know. Try, mon ami, try. Close enough to see it but far enough to be outta reach

Answer (score 1):

Marx objected to aspects of Helvetius’ materialism, Lucretius’ materialism, Locke’s materialism, Epicurus’ materialism, Kant’s materialism, etc.

The so-called “chief defect” summarizes the
problem with all noteworthy progressive philosophies heretofore existing — that they were speculative, and shirked from the practico-theoretical.

To expand your understanding of his critique, read the *Theses* in full, which is propaedeutic to the *German Ideology* that best addresses your question.

Keep in mind that Marx’s materialism is a controversial subject. Marx himself didn’t value his early epistemological works later in life (preferring to them the *Critique of Political-Economy* and the preliminary notes thereto collected under the title, *Grundrisse*).

##### Further Reading

Read Feuerbach's *Lectures on the Essence of Religion*. Or if you want the hard version, *Essence of Christianity*.

Then read Marx's theses on Feuerbach. It will clarify Marx's criticisms. You shall see how much Marx took from Feuerbach.